# Which is best practice to add security headers for django application?

Tags: django, security, nginx

Now which is better for adding [security headers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/middleware/#django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware) configuration
at the application level or the nginx level like

```
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header 'Referrer-Policy' 'origin';
```

Or at django settings

```
SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER=True
SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF=True
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS=True
SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS=36000
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT=True
```

And what if I added them on the two levels, will it make any conflict or any problems on the future?
Sure what about any framework that provide its security middleware, not django specifically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes, it may cause some conflict in your web server, for example, you have to X-Frame-Options in your response header, I suggest you to not do that. handle you're in just one level, do whatever you can with the Django and do the rest with your web server (as I know for example Feature-Policy cant be handle in Django cleanly do this with your web server, nonce hash is not easy in web server and you should do it with your Django !)
I don't know it how much true way, [Django deployment checklist](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/checklist/#https) suggest do SSL redirection with your web server and

you can use [Django-CSP](https://django-csp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to generate the nonce hash and config your [CSP policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy), also you can add [Feature-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Feature-Policy) to Nginx config by :

```
add_header Feature-Policy "accelerometer 'none'; camera 'none'; geolocation 'none'; gyroscope 'none'; magnetometer 'none'; microphone 'none'; payment 'none'; usb 'none'";
```

the best practices available on [OWASP Secure Headers Project](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Secure_Headers_Project) and my [git repo](https://github.com/benyaminsalimi/Secure-Headers) and [here is link of django secure header config](https://github.com/benyaminsalimi/Secure-Headers/blob/master/example/Django_Settings.py)